# Regex operation in python

Tags: python, regex

I am 2 days old to regex,

I have a small query

When I use the below regex statement

```
re.findall('([ad])[\-.\s+]([be])[\-.\s+]([cf])*', 'a-b-c d-e-f')
```

I recieve an output

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

However the output I desire is

```
['a-b-c', 'd-e-f']
```

I've tried ?, $ and other expressions but no luck yet.

Please let me know If the expression can be molded a bit to get the desire output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print re.findall('((?:[ad])[\-.\s+](?:[be])[\-.\s+](?:[cf])*)', 'a-b-c d-e-f')
```

`Capture` the whole string and use `non capturing` groups for the rest.`findall` returns all the captured groups if present any.

Output : `['a-b-c', 'd-e-f']`

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `string.split`?

```
string.split()
```

or

```
re.findall(r'\S+', s)
```

Use `re.finditer`. This won't match `a-b.c`

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in re.finditer(r'\b[ad]([-.\s+])[be]\1[cf]\b', 'a-b-c d-e-f'):
        l.append(i.group())


>>> l
['a-b-c', 'd-e-f']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have capturing groups around all your letters.  If you use a single capturing group, then you will get what you want.  Also, you should get rid of the trailing  '*' because that matches the blank string:

```
>>> re.findall('([ad][\-.\s+][be][\-.\s+][cf])', 'a-b-c d-e-f')
['a-b-c', 'd-e-f']
```